# Write a C++ program that reads integers from standard input until end of file

Tags: c++

> Write a C++ program that reads integers from standard input until end of file.
>   Print out the largest integer that you read in, on a line by itself.
>   
> Any erroneous input (something that is not an integer) should be detected and ignored.
>   
> In the case where no integers are provided at all, print NO INTEGERS and stop.
>   
> The whole program is under 40 lines of code. Just read from cin.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int number;
    int LargerNumber;
    int n = 0;

    cin >> number;

    while(!cin.eof()){
        if(n==0)
            LargerNumber = number;

        if(LargerNumber < number)
            LargerNumber = number;

        n++;
        cin >> number;
    }

    if(n==0)
        cout<<"NO INTEGERS"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"Largest: "<< LargerNumber <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So, this program does compile, but when I build it and run it in the program our teacher told us to use, it does not output the correct statement.

The teacher will input some numbers, and we had to output the biggest integer, but we have to output an error it either there is no integer or output an error if there is character/words in there.

Ex: If the input is this  7 4 19 99 8 309256, the output should be 309256, but my program keeps timing out, or just outputs the first number, 7,

Ex:  Input 2,44,66,83,4,5,-9
output: error negative number

Ex: Input 4,7,-8,22,3,5
output: error negative number

Ex: Input 3,6,8,ad,4,6
output: error ad, not an integer

Ex: Input 55,7,81,2,4,5,9.9,0
output: error 9.9 is not whole integer

Comment: Please don't put an empty line between each and every line of your code. Doing so doesn't make your code more readable

Comment: What did you observe when you ran this program through the debugger?

Comment: Also you don't need to have the variable `n == 0`. It serves no purpose. Simply set `largerNumber = INT_MIN` in the start (in case of negatives) and then you can just compare to see if the input is a larger number.

Comment: @FredLarson It's not "always wrong", and it's not wrong here either (except that `.bad()` would be better, but let's take the OP at face value about their numeric input). Look at the structure of the loop.

Comment: After the first `cin >> number;` you can do `LargerNumber = number;` and drop the `if(n==0)  LargerNumber = number;` from the loop.

Comment: It seems that the problem is that the last number is not checked for the largest which is confusing because of the always wrong link.

Comment: @drescherjm That's true, though then the output should be 99.

Comment: I got 99 for this: http://ideone.com/4W5hnZ if I edit the input and put a number after 309256 it outputs 309256.

Comment: Indeed I believe we do not have a proper [mcve] or some other detail is missing.

Comment: Your program is timing out because you do not clear the bad input. You can check for success with `if (cin >> number)...` If that fails, you need to reset `cin` and skip the bad input: `else {cin.clear(); cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');`}

Comment: isn't this duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57964225/maximum-integer-program-with-stringstream

Comment: Where in your **posted code** is a check for negative number or the output of an error message for negative numbers?  Your example outputs don't match the behavior from the posted code.

Comment: One of the requirements says, "Any erroneous input (something that is not an integer) should be detected and ignored." In order to do that, the program must not assume it will read an integer. Therefore, you if use `cin >> number`, where you've declared `int number`, you'll have to use try/catch to handle the exception. You may find it easier to read a string and convert it to an integer using std::stol (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), which also involves using try/catch to handle the exception.

Comment: @LeeJenkins `cin >> number` will not throw if you give it a string of non numeric characters. It'll just set the fail state on `cin`.